# Node.js CPU profiling syscall

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, profiling

Node.js app which calls 1 http backend. after putting some load on the app with cpu profiler enabled i got the below result.

[Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

ticks parent  name
  53352   41.9%  syscall

15733   12.4%  write

what does syscall and write  means in this context.

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out? I'm having the same problem